# Trying to add text to my input via javascript

Tags: javascript, html, frontend

So I need to generate something that would look like this via javascript:

```
<label class="checkbox-container">
    <input type="checkbox">Some text
    <span class="checkmark"></span>
</label>
```

Currently I have this:

```
var label = document.createElement('label');
label.classList.add('checkbox-container');

var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');

var span = document.createElement('span');
span.classList.add('checkmark');

label.appendChild(input);
label.appendChild(span);
```

Which makes everything except the "Some text" right after my input. I saw a couple of answers using jquery but i was wondering if this was possible only using js?

Comment: if my answer solved your question, you should mark it as the answer  :)

Comment: @Anthony I had to wait 10 minutes before marking answered!

Comment: ahhh right right. im still a n00b myself lol

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
const text = document.createTextNode('Some text')
label.appendChild(text)
```

That should do the trick.

As a side note, your `<label>` element should be a sibling of `<input>` and `<span>`, whereas `<form>` should contain everything.

```
<form>
  <label></label>
  <input>
  <span></span>
  <label></label>
  <input>
  <span></span>
</form>
```

Comment: @ChristopheSirois NP! i made an edit/comment regarding the structure of ur code, which is better practice!

Comment: If `label` does not contain a form field, then it must use the `for` attribute that points to the `id` of a form field, otherwise, the element has no value.

Comment: @ChristopheSirois @ScottMarcus yep! here is some info about [`<label>`](https://www.w3schools.com/tags/tag_label.asp)

Comment: Please don't use W3 Schools as a reference as it is widely known to often have incomplete, out of date or flat out wrong information. Instead, use **[MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/label)** as this is known to be an authoritative source.

Comment: @ScottMarcus duly noted. i just find it's easier than MDN for beginners to digest

Comment: @Anthony Thanks, I will change the structure of my code!

Comment: @ScottMarcus Will def check out MDN instead of W3

Comment: @Anthony To add a second one right below do I do it in the same form or create a new one?

Comment: @ChristopheSirois add a 2nd what? a 2nd label?

Comment: @Anthony Yes a second input with a label

Comment: @ChristopheSirois I updated my code. or did you want to do it via JS?

Comment: @Anthony HTML like that is perf, I know how to do it in JS!

Answer (score 0):

You should simply append string as HTML. Consider below code:

```js
var label = document.createElement('label');
label.classList.add('checkbox-container');

var input = document.createElement('INPUT');
input.setAttribute('type', 'checkbox');

var span = document.createElement('span');
span.classList.add('checkmark');

label.appendChild(input);
label.insertAdjacentHTML( 'beforeend', "Some Text" );
label.appendChild(span);

document.body.append(label);
```